# How to pass parameters to guicified TestNG test from Surefire Maven plugin?

Tags: maven-2, testng, guice, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm using Maven + Surefire + TestNG + Guice (latest stable ones)

I have "large" test that requires Guice to run.
Basically I'm doing it this way:

```
@Test(groups = "large")
@Guice(modules = FooLargeTest.Module.class)
public class FooLargeTest {
  public static class Module extends AbstractModule {
    public void configure() {
      bindConstant().annotatedWith(FooPort.class).to(5000);
      // ... some other test bindings
    }
  }
  @Inject Provider<Foo> fooProvider;
  @Test
  public void testFoo() {
    Foo foo = fooProvider.get() // here injection of port is done
                                // it could not be passed to constructor
    // ... actual test of foo
  }
}
```

The problem is that `FooPort` is hardcoded to `5000`. It is a Maven property, so the first try was to use next Surefire configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <fooPort>${foo.port}</fooPort>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

And after that request it like `System.getProperty("fooPort")`. Unfortunately, documentation says, that this is only for JUnit test. At least I could not see this system variable during debugging of a test. I tried `forkMode` both default one and `never`, it does not change anything. For TestNG tests it's recommended to make it this way:

```
<properties>
  <property>
    <name>fooPort</name>
    <value>${foo.port}</value>
  </property>
</properties>
```

But now I should use this property from Guice, so it should be given somehow to GuiceModule, I've tried it next way:

```
@Test(groups = "large")
@Guice(moduleFactory = FooLargeTest.ModuleFactory.class)
public class FooLargeTest {
  public static class ModuleFactory extends AbstractModule {
    private final String fooPort = fooPort;
    @Parameters("fooPort")
    public ModuleFactory(String fooPort) {
      this.fooPort = fooPort;
    }
    public Module createModule(final ITestContext context, Class<?> testClass) { 
      return new AbstractModule {
        public void configure() {
          bindConstant().annotatedWith(FooPort.class).to(fooPort);
          // ... some other test bindings
        }
      }
    }
  }
  @Inject Provider<Foo> fooProvider;
  @Test
  public void testFoo() {
    Foo foo = fooProvider.get() // here injection of port is done
    // actual test of foo
  }
}
```

But this way was also a failure as creator for `modulefactories` does not take `@Parameters` into account and thus could not create instance of a factory.

Looks like I should try to get some data from `ITestContext context`, but I do not know how and if the data is there or if there is some simpler way to do what I want.

Thanks for a response.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran a quick test and properties seem to be passed correctly to TestNG:

```
    <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng-single.yaml</suiteXmlFile>
      </suiteXmlFiles>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <foo>bar</foo>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
```

My suite file calls the test class B, which contains:

```
@Test
public void f() {
  System.out.println(" property:" + System.getProperty("foo"));
}
```

and running it with Maven shows:

```
property:bar
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.358 sec
```

I'm not using Guice in this simple example but that's the only difference between your code and mine.

Feel free to create a small Maven project reproducing your problem, make sure that I can compile it and then email it to me.

Comment: Looks like I could reproduce my problem. Here is shrinked project. Results of running a project with `mvn test` and `mvn -X test` are attached. [attached zip](http://narod.ru/disk/15469163001/maven-testng.zip.html)

Answer (score -1):

I tried below test and works fine

My Pom file

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<groups>Regression</groups> -->
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <environment>UAT</environment>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My TestNG test

```
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class TestAuthentication {

    @Test (groups = { "Sniff", "Regression" })
    public void validAuthenticationTest(){
        System.out.println(" property:" + System.getProperty("environment"));
    }

    @Test (groups = { "Regression" },parameters = {"environment"})
    public void failedAuthenticationTest(String environment){
        System.out.println("Regression-"+environment);
    }

    @Parameters("environment")
    @Test (groups = { "Sniff"})
    public void newUserAuthenticationTest(String environment){
        System.out.println("Sniff-"+environment);
    }
}
```