# Passing parameters from jenkins to maven

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

I set my variables in jenkins like this :
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mipCP.jpg

testngVersion

I want to use in my pom.xml:

```
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>%{testngVersion}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

I tried :

```
 <version>%{env.testngVersion}</version>
```

What im doing wrong ?
I keep getting:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Testing: Could not resolve dependencies for project Framework:Testing:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.testng:testng:jar:%{env.testngVersion}: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.testng:testng:jar:%{env.testngVersion}: Could not transfer artifact org.testng:testng:pom:%{env.testngVersion}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not %{...}

It should be `${testngVersion}`

Comment: You are the greatest!

Comment: adding in pom <properities> :
    <testng>${testngVersion}</testng>

    System.getProperty("testng");

is returning null; why ?

Comment: `testng` is not system property :(.  What do you try to do exactly?

Comment: I want to pass variables from jenkins through maven to testng (java)

Now its working in maven, but how to pass it further to testng?

Comment: @MichalK, oh i see.  check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245411/how-to-pass-java-code-a-parameter-from-maven-for-testing