# retrive command line -D option in Java maven project

Tags: java, maven

[Maven CLI Options Reference](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html) says -D option define a system property.
The question is how to retrieve this option in Java Code.

I tried the following snippet and command, but couldn't retrieve it.

```
public class Test2Class {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println((new Properties()).get("env"));
    }
}
```

*mvn -Dtest=Test2Class test -Denv=dev*

What else should I do to make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass java code a parameter from maven for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245411/how-to-pass-java-code-a-parameter-from-maven-for-testing)

Comment: Can you clarify your question with more details ? What you wants to achieve exactly so far ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Properties p = System.getProperties();
p.get("my.property");
```

or

```
System.getProperty("my.property")
```

Have a look here: [How to pass java code a parameter from maven for testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245411/how-to-pass-java-code-a-parameter-from-maven-for-testing)